# Google Sign-In - returns empty profile

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I'm trying to integrate Google's Sign-In. Running a basic example on a local python SimpleHTTPServer, works fine, except for the fact that the getBasicProfile() method returns an empty object. It does not show a name, email, imageUrl, ID...

The snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
     <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="123456789_fake_987654321.apps.googleusercontent.com">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    <a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a>

    <script>
        function onSignIn(googleUser) {
            var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
            console.log(profile.getId()); 
            console.log(profile.getName());
            console.log(profile.getImageUrl());
            console.log(profile.getEmail());
        }
        function signOut() {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                console.log('User signed out.');
            });
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The api opens a new window, allows me to enter my credentials and logs me in and out without any problem. Only the googleUser object, which is defined, keeps on returning empty properties.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the python SimpleHTTPServer was using port 8000.

I had to add http://localhost:8000, with port number, instead of http://localhost, to the restricted JavaScript Origins and redirect URIs of my Google's client ID.